# Checking that a user has correctly entered an IP Address

Tags: c#, validation

I am currently working on a C# project where I need to validate the text that a user has entered into a text box.

One of the validations required is that it checks to ensure that an IP address has been entered correctly.

How would I go about doing this validation of the IP address.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Regular expressions: \b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b

Comment: @reggie: not all those patterns are valid. A/B/C nets etc.

Comment: Does this need to take into account IP v4 and v6?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that you are only concerned with validating IPv4 IP Address strings in X.X.X.X format. If so, this code is straight forward for that task:

```
string ip = "127.0.0.1";
string[] parts = ip.Split('.');
if (parts.Length < 4)
{
    // not a IPv4 string in X.X.X.X format
}
else
{
    foreach(string part in parts)
    {
        byte checkPart = 0;
        if (!byte.TryParse(part, out checkPart))
        {
            // not a valid IPv4 string in X.X.X.X format
        }
    }
    // it is a valid IPv4 string in X.X.X.X format
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use [IPAddress.Parse Method .NET Framework 1.1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.parse%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). Or, if you are using .NET 4.0, see documentation for [IPAddress.TryParse Method .NET Framework 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.tryparse.aspx).

This method determines if the contents of a string represent a valid IP address. In .NET 1.1, the return value is the IP address. In .NET 4.0, the return value indicates success/failure, and the IP address is returned in the IPAddress passed as an `out` parameter in the method call.

edit: alright I'll play the game for bounty :)  Here's a sample implementation as an extension method, requiring C# 3+ and .NET 4.0:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace IPValidator
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            Action<string> TestIP = (ip) => Console.Out.WriteLine (ip + " is valid? " + ip.IsValidIP ());

            TestIP ("99");
            TestIP ("99.99.99.99");
            TestIP ("255.255.255.256");
            TestIP ("abc");
            TestIP ("192.168.1.1");
        }

    }

    internal static class IpExtensions
    {
        public static bool IsValidIP (this string address)
        {
            if (!Regex.IsMatch (address, @"\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b"))
                return false;

            IPAddress dummy;
            return IPAddress.TryParse (address, out dummy);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Normally just-a-link answers are wrong but this is very accurate. All the same, summarize in a few lines to make a proper answer. And maybe link to Fx4,

Comment: What kind of summary is necessary?  IMO a "google it for me" question gets to do a bit of homework afterwards, since they obviously didn't do any beforehand.  Not every answer is completely free.

Comment: Thanks, this worked sort of. However, when I am entering an IP Address say 127.0.0.1. It says that it is valid before each dot. I.e. If I type 127 it will consider that as valid, when I put 127. this won't be valid again, and when I put 127.0 this will be considered as valid again. This seems a bit strange that its doing this as 127 and 127.0 are not IP addresses

Comment: Yes they are.  Dotted-quad notation is a more human-readable form of raw 32-bit numbers, which is what IP addresses ultimately are.  Try `ping 134744072`.

Comment: Oh right didn't realise that, is there a way to check to make sure it is in the readable form like a normal IP address, i.e. 127.0.0.1 would be valid but 127 wouldn't be

Comment: reggie's regexp + the above `Parse`.

Comment: Returns false on valid IP address fe80::202:b3ff:fe1e:8329

Comment: Boardy only gave examples of IPv4.  He didn't like my completely-compatible parser of not using the regex.

Comment: @insta, yeah I certainly wouldn't vote yours down, there's a lot of ambiguity in the question. It could be just IPv4 if it isn't planned for long-term or fully public use, and I could see how someone could type 127 or 127.0.0 by accident so it's worth catching, but it's not clear just what *is* wanted other than old dotted quads that aren't going to be the correct data for an increasing number of cases.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see if the IP address actually exists, you can use the [Ping class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping%28v=VS.80%29.aspx).

Comment: Be aware for some stupid design decision, the Ping class will throw an exception if the ping fails for any reason.

Comment: And ping can be blocked on existing IPs.

Answer (score 1):

insta's answer was closer before he added the incorrect regexp.

```
public static bool IsValidIP(string ipAddress)
{
  IPAddress unused;
  return IPAddress.TryParse(ipAddress, out unused);
}
```

Or since the OP doesn't want to include integer IPv4 addresses that aren't full dotted quads:

```
public static bool IsValidIP(string ipAddress)
{
  IPAddress unused;
  return IPAddress.TryParse(ipAddress, out unused)
    &&
    (
        unused.AddressFamily != AddressFamily.InterNetwork
        ||
        ipAddress.Count(c => c == '.') == 3
    );
}
```

Testing:

`IsValidIP("fe80::202:b3ff:fe1e:8329")` returns `true` (correct).

`IsValidIP("127.0.0.1")` returns `true` (correct).

`IsValidIP("What's an IP address?")` returns `false` (correct).

`IsValidIP("127")` returns `true` with first version, `false` with second (correct).

`IsValidIP("127.0")` returns `true` with first version, `false` with second (correct).

Comment: Hana, Thanks for your help but this returns the same thing as mentioned before 127.0 comes back as true, which isn't what I want. I would only want the full ip address to be true, i.e. 127.0.0.1

Comment: @Boardy. Simply enough done. With fe80::202:b3ff:fe1e:8329 though it could as likely be written fe80:0:0:0:202:b3ff:fe1e:8329 and there are several other variants. Not sure what you'd want to do there.

Comment: Further edit: slightly faster and I think a bit clearer on intent of the code.

Comment: LOL. And another because that had silliness.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a regex.

```
^((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]\d|\d)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]\d|\d)$
```

Using named groups, it could be clearer. It is written in Ruby. I don't know C# but I guess that the regex support is complete in that language and that named groups might exist.

```
 /(?<number>(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]\d|\d)){0}^(\g<number>\.){3}\g<number>$/
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution:

```
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Net;
```

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Return true if the IP address is valid.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="address"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public bool TestIpAddress (string address)
    {
        PingReply reply;
        Ping pingSender = new Ping ();

        try
        {
            reply = pingSender.Send (address);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return reply.Status == IPStatus.Success;
    }
```